# pyspark transformer can not handle dataframe columns with spaces

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, transform, spark-cassandra-connector

Using Pyspark to read data from Cassandra database.

Packages:

```
from  pyspark.ml.feature import SQLTransformer
from transform.Base import Transform
```

I have loaded the data it looks like below

```
+----+--------------------+-------+---+
|time|   MEM UTI PERC %   |devId  |Lid|
+----+--------------------+-------+---+
| 482|         8.661052632|      6| 20|
| 654|         9.162190612|      6| 20|
| 364|         8.219230769|      6| 20|
```

When I apply SQLTransform, which SQL STATEMENT AS

```
self.sqlstatement = "SELECT Time,MEM UTI PERC % FROM __THIS__ WHERE "

sqltrans = SQLTransformer()
sqltrans.setStatement(self.sqlstatement)
new_df = sqltrans.transform(sparkdf)
```

It throws error

```
mismatched input 'UTI' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 19)
```

So I modified the SQL Statement to wrap the spaced column inside double quotes/single quotes like below

```
SELECT Time,"MEM UTI PERC %" FROM __THIS__ WHERE
```

This time, the transformer doesn't throw exception but instead in replaces all the value of that spaced column with same column name , like below

```
+----+--------------+
|Time|MEM UTI PERC %|
+----+--------------+
| 212|MEM UTI PERC %|
|  26|MEM UTI PERC %|
```

I want to get data properly like

```
+----+--------------+
|Time|MEM UTI PERC %|
+----+--------------+
| 212|20.7          |
|  26|40.0          |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape column names with hyphen in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889630/how-to-escape-column-names-with-hyphen-in-spark-sql), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963605/select-spark-dataframe-column-with-special-character-in-it-using-selectexpr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728748/1053697
Thanks , escaping with backticks(` `) does works for columns with spaces as well. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the column name in single quotes like this and see if it works:

```
self.sqlstatement = "SELECT Time,'MEM UTI PERC %' FROM __THIS__ WHERE "
```

Alternatively, you might need to escape the quotes this way:

```
self.sqlstatement = "SELECT Time,\"MEM UTI PERC %\" FROM __THIS__ WHERE "
```

See which one works. Cheers!

Comment: First option, I already tried and second option(escape character ), I just tried , both doesn't work. :)